# SharePoint DEsigner 2010 - how to get workflow status?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SPD 2010 workflow that uses the start approval process task.  This activity allows user to approve or deny a request from the task item.  If the user rejects the item, then the workflow status gets set to "Rejected".

My question is how do i get the current workflow status value?
i.e. if the user rejects it, then i want the workflow to branch.  But how do i branch based on workflow status?

I tried Current Item: Approval Status.  But that does not seem to be correct.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The workflow status are constants (integers), so you'll need to refer to a list like:

- Status: Value
- Not Started: 0
- Failed on Start: 1
- In Progress: 2
- Error Occurred: 3
- Canceled: 4
- Completed: 5
- Failed on Start(Retrying): 6
- Error Occurred (Retrying): 7
- Canceled: 15
- Approved: 16
- Rejected: 17

So you'd need to check if Approval Status equals 17.